# Why I can't render text in div

Tags: reactjs

This is my first project using React.js and I follow this steps for create a Hello World (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html)

I import React.js in head tag but why my code doesn't works? index.html is just only blank page

index.html

```
<html>
    <title>
        My first project using React.js
    </title>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
        </div>
        <script>
        ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>Hello world!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you forgot to give the reference of babel, use this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

And specify the type of the script also `type=text/babel`.

Check the working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>
        My first project using React.js
    </title>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"/>
        <script type='text/jsx'>
            ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello world!</h1>,
                document.getElementById('root')
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's difference between text/label and text/jsx? I see some examples which uses text/jsx

Comment: it will tell that what this script contains, when we specify text/jsx babel transpile into plain `javascript`, if you do not specify the type babel will not do own job and it will throw error, try to run the code without type you will see the error :)